# why the storage explore google chrome plugin did not show

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have already installed the google chrome extension [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) in my google chrome browser. Now I can use the Storage Area Explorer google chrome plugin to check the local storage data in the Storage Explorer tab:

[image]

but in some plugin extension(the extension was developed by myself and did not publish to google chrome plugin store, the google chrome extension plugin manifest version was v3) page, the Storage Area Explorer did not show.

[image]

why did this happen? is it possible to make it show?

Comment: You're opening it on the wrong page. Open a page of your extension first, then open devtools on that page.

Comment: the dev tools on that page did not show the Storage Area Explorer tab.@wOxxOm

Comment: I figure out that I should open the plugin option page to check the local storage.@wOxxOm

Comment: That's what I said.